# Validating a non-mapped field (radio button) in Symfony 2 fails

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

Other fields are existing and mapped to an entity. Only 1 field is non-mapped a radio button with the code below. All the rest of the fields are working fine.

```
add->('verifyLicence','choice', 
           array('mapped' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'choices' => array(0=>'Yes', 1=>'No'),
                'constraints' => array(
                    new Assert\NotNull(array('message' => 'You need to verify the licence info.')),
                )));
```

But whenever I submit the form the validation doesn't not kick in. What seems to be the problem?

**UPDATE**
Here is my controller:

```
public function submitAction() {
    $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType($obj));
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
           // Some more codes.
        } else {
            $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($hire);
        }
    }

    return [
        'hire'     => $hire,
        'action'   => $action,
        'errors'   => $errors ?: [],
        'form'     => $form->createView(),
        'calendar' => $calendar,
    ];
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver
        ->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => "Entity\Driver",
            'show_operator' => false,
            'code' => '',
            'action' => '',
        ))
        ->addAllowedTypes([
            'show_operator' => 'bool',
            'code' => 'string',
            'action' => 'string',
        ]);
}
```

Here is my view:

```
{{ form_widget(form.verifyLicence) }}
{{ form_errors(form.verifyLicence) }}
```

Comment: try simply setting 'required' => true instead of find for a validator

Comment: Please post your controller action code. Are you calling `$form->isValid()`?

Comment: @sjagr I've just updated my question.

Comment: @jack I think that is true by default.

Comment: Check if you not overriding any validation group with `setDefaultOptions()` method for example. If you are using validation groups, you must to pass it to the `Constraint`.

Comment: @Aistis I've added the `setDefaultOptions` function. Do you find any problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Assert\False` validator in this case.

```
'constraints' => [
    new Assert\False(['message' => 'You need to verify the licence info.']),
]));
```

I suggest you to rewrite the form field like this:

```
$builder->add(
    'verifyLicence',
    'choice', 
    [
        'mapped' => false,
        'required' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false,
        'choices' => [1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No'],
        'constraints' => [
            new Assert\True(['message' => 'You need to verify the licence info.']),
        ]
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the required attribute as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#required).

So you can add as:

```
add->('verifyLicence','choice', array('mapped' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'choices' => array(0=>'Yes', 1=>'No'),
                'required' => true,
                ));
```

Comment: I think that is true by default. Anyway, I've tried it but still the same.